# Populating option in react component with key value pair

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am trying to populate the option with authors name dynamically by providing a key value pair and want the result as shown but the result is not like but instead it displays four different forms for each author.
Please refer to images for a clear view of my question.

This is what I got:
[image]

```
import { gql ,useQuery} from '@apollo/client';



const getAuthorsQuery = gql`
    {
        authors{
            name
            id
        }
    }
`;
function AddBook() {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(getAuthorsQuery);
  
    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;
  
        console.log(data)
    
        return   data.authors.map(author => {
            
          return (
            <form id="add-book">
            <div className="field">
                <label>Book name:</label>
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
            <div className="field">
                <label>Genre:</label>
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
            <div className="field">
                <label >Author:</label>
                <select  >
                    
                    <option key={author.id} value ={author.id}>Select Authors</option>
                    {author.name}
                </select>
            </div>
            <button>+</button>

        </form>
             
          )
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using map for entire form use at options alone.

```
{data.authors.map(author => <option key={author.id} value ={author.id}>Select Authors</option>)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your order of operations wrong.  You have placed the loop way too early in the flow of your code, and are therefore creating all of the JSX for the entire form for each option.

You can declare JSX as a variable earlier in the method and then use it in your final return JSX by wrapping it in {}

Also, you want to put the author.name inside of the option, and your Select Author option should have an empty value; like this:

```
let options = [];
for (let author in authors) {
    options.push(<option key={author.id} value={author.id}>author.name</option>);
}

...

<select>
    <option value="">Select Authors</option>
    {options}
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you solved it by the first answer given by Keerthi